# How to schedule a database task ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've built a simple student management system. In my application, I need a scheduler for 1st day of every month student due amount will increase by the given number and update student info in the database.

I tried with hangfire and it worked well on the local machine, but it did not work when I deployed the application to the web server.

Now how can I do these kinds of mechanisms?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder why hangfire didn't work when you deployed the application to web the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IHostedService interface and register using:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyScheduler>();
```

**MyScheduler**

```
public class MyScheduler : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Start a timer that will run every x minutes to see
        // if the conditions are met to perform your action
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Dispose of Timer
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Just to add on this cause it is a great answer, from my understanding of the question you want to run a job that updates your database. If it is a sql server database you can also use a scheduled job to run whatever operation you want on the database directly. Its another option if your job is database specific :)

Comment: I need this run once on a certain day of every month. How can set this on a timer?

Comment: You don't necessarily know how long your app pool will be up for so your Hosted service will start whenever the app pool is recycled and then the timer can run every period suitable to you to check whether the first day of the month job is required.  Perhaps a daily timer is suitable for you.  That Timer callback will then do the work to see if: a) we are in the first day of the month and b) the job has not already been run for this month.  How you implement the logic to know when one is due and whether one has been executed is up to you.